# Bash JQ FormData object to encoded parameters string

Tags: bash, sh, jq

I would like using the JQ command line to transform a FormData json object into a string like `id=johndoe&password=secret&foo=bar`

```
 {
      "name": "example",
      "auth_url": "http://example.com/login",
      "form_data": {
          "id": "johndoe",
          "password": "secret",
          "foo": "bar"
      }
 }
```

So far, I came up with this function, which works, but doesn't look elegant or optimized

```
function form_data_to_encoded() {
    local obj=$1
    form_data_keys=$(echo $obj | jq '.form_data | keys')
    length=$(echo $form_data_keys | jq 'length')
    encoded=""
    for ((i=0; i<$length; i++)); do
        key=$(echo "$form_data_keys" | jq --raw-output ".[$i]")
        value=$(echo "$obj" | jq --raw-output ".form_data.$key")
        encoded="$encoded$key=$value"
        if (( ((i+1)) < "$length" )); then
            encoded="$encoded&"
        fi
    done
    echo "$encoded"
}
```

Is there a way to create achieve this using only one (or fewer) JQ filter ?
Thanks for your help or insight :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Format Strings and Escaping together with String Interpolation (both section titles in the jq manual) in a map, followed by reduce:

```
jq -r '
  .form_data | 
  to_entries | 
  map(@uri "\(.key)=\(.value)") | 
  reduce .[1:][] as $i (.[0]; .+"&"+$i)
'
```